# How do you fix FileNotFound Errors (Glide)?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-glide, filenotfoundexception

I am writing a chatting app and I am on the part where users can send texts/pictures (saved in Firebase) to each other. I am using Glide to upload pictures from Firebase to ImageView. The pictures are being uploaded correctly ; however, the texts are uploaded as the placeholder for my pictures.

**Code**

```
package com.example.realtimechat.chats

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.example.realtimechat.R
import com.example.realtimechat.common.Constants
import com.example.realtimechat.common.Extras
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

class MessagesAdapter(private val context: Context,
                      private val messageList: List<MessageModel> = mutableListOf()): RecyclerView.Adapter<MessagesAdapter.MessageViewHolder>() {


    private lateinit var mAuth: FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MessagesAdapter.MessageViewHolder {
        val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_message_layout, parent, false)
        return MessageViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MessagesAdapter.MessageViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val message: MessageModel = messageList[position]
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        val currentUserId = mAuth.currentUser!!.uid
        val fromUserId = message.MessageFrom

        val sfd: SimpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm")
        val dateTime = sfd.format(message.MessageTime)

        val splitString: Array<String> = dateTime.split(" ").toTypedArray()
        val messageTime = splitString[1]

        Log.i("message time:", messageTime)

        if(fromUserId == currentUserId){
            if(message.MessageType.equals(Constants.MESSAGE_TYPE_TEXT)){
                holder.llSent.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                holder.llSentImage.visibility = View.GONE
            }else{
                holder.llSent.visibility = View.GONE
                holder.llSentImage.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }

            holder.llReceived.visibility = View.GONE
            holder.llReceivedImage.visibility = View.GONE

            holder.tvSentMessage.text = message.Message
            holder.tvSentMessageTime.text = messageTime
            holder.tvImageSentTime.text = messageTime
            Glide.with(context)
                .load(message.Message)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_image)
                .into(holder.ivSent)
        }else{
            if(message.MessageType.equals(Constants.MESSAGE_TYPE_TEXT)){
                holder.llReceived.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                holder.llReceivedImage.visibility = View.GONE
            }else{
                holder.llReceived.visibility = View.GONE
                holder.llReceivedImage.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }

            holder.llSent.visibility = View.GONE
            holder.llSentImage.visibility = View.GONE

            holder.tvReceivedMessage.text = message.Message
            holder.tvReceivedMessageTime.text = messageTime
            holder.tvImageReceivedTime.text = messageTime
            Glide.with(context)
                .load(message.Message)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_image)
                .into(holder.ivReceived)
        }

        holder.clMessage.setTag(R.id.TAG_MESSAGE, message.Message)
        holder.clMessage.setTag(R.id.TAG_MESSAGE_ID, message.Message)
        holder.clMessage.setTag(R.id.TAG_MESSAGE_TYPE, message.Message)

        holder.clMessage.setOnClickListener{view ->
            val messageType: String = view.getTag(R.id.TAG_MESSAGE_TYPE).toString()
            val uri: Uri = Uri.parse(view.getTag(R.id.TAG_MESSAGE_TYPE).toString())
            if(messageType == Constants.MESSAGE_TYPE_VIDEO){
                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)
                intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/mp4")
                context.startActivity(intent)
            }else if(messageType == Constants.MESSAGE_TYPE_IMAGE){
                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)
                intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/jpg")
                context.startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return messageList.size
    }

    inner class MessageViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val llSent: LinearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.llSent)
        val llReceived: LinearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.llReceived)
        val llSentImage: LinearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.llSentImage)
        val llReceivedImage: LinearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.llReceivedImage)
        val tvSentMessage: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSentMessage)
        val tvSentMessageTime: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSentMessageTime)
        val tvReceivedMessage: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvReceivedMessage)
        val tvReceivedMessageTime: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvReceivedMessageTime)
        val ivSent: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivSent)
        val ivReceived: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivReceived)
        val tvImageSentTime: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSentImageTime)
        val tvImageReceivedTime: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvReceivedImageTime)
        val clMessage: ConstraintLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.clMessage)

    }

}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/clMessage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llSent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@drawable/sent_message_background"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:visibility="visible">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSentMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:autoLink="all"
            android:textColorLink="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            tools:text="What's up man" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSentMessageTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="10:00"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llSentImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/llSent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivSent"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/sent_message_background"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_image"
            android:contentDescription="Sent Image" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSentImageTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="10:00"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llReceived"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@drawable/received_message_background"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/llSent"
        tools:visibility="visible">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvReceivedMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:autoLink="all"
            android:textColorLink="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            tools:text="What's up man" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvReceivedMessageTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="10:00"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llReceivedImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/llReceived"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivReceived"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/received_message_background"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_image"
            android:contentDescription="Received Image"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvReceivedImageTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="10:00"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**The problem** ***appears*** **to be in the `OnBindViewHolder` function specifically:**

```
Glide.with(context)
                .load(message.Message)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_image)
                .into(holder.ivSent)
```

**and**

```
Glide.with(context)
                .load(message.Message)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_image)
                .into(holder.ivReceived)
```

I have used Logcat to for more details. `message.Message` returned a correct value, it is just that the text value is being converted into an image from the drawable folder.

**P.S.** The logcat error message tells me that the file is not found. From my knowledge, this is because when I am doing `Glide.with(context).load(message.Message)`, the system is trying to find the image file for the text, which is isn't available since there is only a text. (Correct me if I am wrong please)

Any solutions to this will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: share the value which message.Message returns. Make sure it is an image URL

Comment: @SantoshDhoundiyal message.Message returns both messages of the user and the image URL

Comment: in .load(message.Message) pass only image url value like image_url = "http://example.com/img/image.jpg",   

 Glide.with(context)
                .load(image_url )
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_image)
                .into(holder.ivReceived)

Comment: as Santosh said above , load() function expects an image url, your message format seems to be off.